# Robot framework download file using GET method

Tags: rest, robotframework

I am testing the REST api for download file, so when I am executing GET method using requests.py in robot framework it gives PDF file which i need to create as local file.

Please help me how to create the local PDF file am getting as a response of GET in robot framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a GET, it should be something like:

```
${response} =  requests.get('https://your_url_with_PDF')
```

Then if you want to store the response in a file, just import OperatingSystem Robot Framework library and do:

```
Create File  your_path  ${response.content}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply..
Actually instead of 
"Create File"  I used Create Binary File"